# Find a certain checkbox using its value

Tags: javascript, jquery

So the thing Is I want to check a certain checkbox using it's value, because I have no other way of doing so, since there is no elementId, and all other proprities are the same. Here is the pic explaining.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ARXY.png)

I tried these codes but none of them worked.

```js
//For the first one I tried to count all checkboxes and search for it using 
// innerText
for(var i=0; i< document("input:radio").length; i++)
{
  if( document.getElementsByTagName("RADIO")[i].innerText == " H") 
 { document.getElementsByTagName("RADIO")[i].checked =true;
   break;}}
//Here I changed the way to reach the elements since the first one
//always gave 0 as a count
for(var i=0; i< document("input:radio").length; i++)
{
  if( document("input:radio")[i].innerHTML == " H") 
 { document("input:radio")[i].checked = true;
   break;}}
```

I also found some codes in jQuery but for some reason it doesnt work, And I want it to be in **javaScript**.

Comment: `input` is an “empty” element, so checking for `.innerText` does not make much sense to begin with. That letter `H` you are looking for there has no real connection to your checkbox at all, other than that it _follows_ it in the DOM. Calling this `H` the “value” of this checkbox makes no sense to begin with - the actual value would be `M` in the example you have shown.

Comment: That input thing I am not really sure what it is I just found it online, Now about innerText, I used it to find a certain ( a href) it worked fine, I tried using it on this matter since each checkbox has a text, it didnt work that's why I am asking for an alternative which can only be it's value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
var valueToSearchFor = "your_value";
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var elem of inputs) { 
    if (elem.type == "radio") { // if is a radio button
         if (elem.value == valueToSearchFor) {
             console.log("Found: ", elem);
         }
    }
}
```

You can also use `document.querySelector()`

```
var valueToSearchFor = "your_value";
var checkBoxes = document.querySelector("input[type='radio']");
for (var elem of checkBoxes) { 
     if (elem.value == valueToSearchFor) {
         console.log('Found: ', elem);
     }
}
```

Comment: it keeps telling me that there is a messing " ; "

Comment: Thanks for your effort I'll try to find out why it keeps teling me that there is a missing ;
Maybe it is related to the IE version

Comment: I think the problem is the input type is hidden that's what I found in the code

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery use `[<attribute>="<value">]` (the parentheses are optional if there aren't spaces), as follows:

```js
$('input[type=radio][value=H2]').prop('checked', true);
// For old versions of jQuery:
// $('input[type=radio][value=H2]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" value="H1" name="H"> H1
<input type="radio" value="H2" name="H"> H2
```

Without jQuery, use `document.querySelector()` that gets a CSS selector and returns the first element matches the selector, as follows:

```js
document.querySelector('input[type=radio][value=H2]').checked = true;
```

```html
<input type="radio" value="H1" name="H"> H1
<input type="radio" value="H2" name="H"> H2
```

Comment: When I use this code //document.querySelector('input[type=radio][value=H2]').checked = true;//
It tells me ( It was in french I translated it) : The object does not handle the property or method "querySelector"

Ofc after changing the value to M, since it is the value I have

Comment: What is the browser you using?

Comment: IE and I Dont understand what you really mean by snipppet

Comment: @MohamedChebbi Please provide the version of IE. Compatibility has changed a lot for different versions of browsers. Especially IE. A snippet is a code snippet (code you can run) in the answer of your question.

Answer (score 1):

in javascript on [modern browser](https://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector)! you can use querySelector:

```
var mInput = document.querySelector("input[value='M']")
if (mInput.checked) {
    //radio 'M' is checked
}else {
    //radio 'M' is not checked
}
```

to check if it's checked:

```
if(document.querySelector("input[value='M']") === true )
```

but i think what you really want to achieve is query for the checked radio and get the value:

```
var gender = document.querySelector("input[name=contactFormGender]:checked").value
```

hope this help you

Comment: What I really want is to find the checkBox with the value (X) and check it

Comment: so mInput = document.querySelector("input[value='M']") do this :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
// Check is Radio is checked
var checkChecked = function(el){
  var check = document.querySelector("input[type=radio][value='"+ el +"']");
  return (check.checked ? true : false);
}

// Function for checked by Value
function triggerCheck(el){
   document.querySelector("input[type=radio][value='"+ el +"']").checked = true;
}

triggerCheck("M2");


console.log("H1 Is checked? " + checkChecked("H1"));
console.log("M2 Is checked? " + checkChecked("M2"));
console.log("K1 Is checked? " + checkChecked("K1"));
```

```html
<input type="radio" value="H1" name="H"> H1
<input type="radio" value="H2" name="H"> H2
<br>
<input type="radio" value="M1" name="M"> M1
<input type="radio" value="M2" name="M"> M2
<br>
<input type="radio" checked="checked" value="K1" name="K"> K1
<input type="radio" value="K2" name="K"> K2
```

Answer (score 0):

For further  explanation this is the source

```css
<DIV CLASS="RadioDIV">
<SPAN CLASS="CheckRadioHeaderTxt"><IMG SRC="webresources/icons/mandatory.gif" ALT="Mandatory" CLASS="DAMandatoryIcon">Sexe<BR></SPAN>
                <INPUT  CLASS="Radio" TYPE="RADIO"  NAME="contactFormGender" VALUE="M"><SPAN CLASS="CheckRadioTxt"> H<BR></SPAN><INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="IVP_contactFormGender" VALUE="IVP_No_Model_Connection#null#noFormatMaskPropSet"/>
                <INPUT  CLASS="Radio" TYPE="RADIO"  NAME="contactFormGender" VALUE="F"><SPAN CLASS="CheckRadioTxt"> F<BR></SPAN><INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="IVP_contactFormGender" VALUE="IVP_No_Model_Connection#null#noFormatMaskPropSet"/>
                <INPUT  CLASS="Radio" TYPE="RADIO" CHECKED  NAME="contactFormGender" VALUE="N"><SPAN CLASS="CheckRadioTxt"> Aucun<BR></SPAN><INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="IVP_contactFormGender" VALUE="IVP_No_Model_Connection#null#noFormatMaskPropSet"/>
              </DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it ALL I needed to do it to make a group of radios that have the same ID, then get each ones value, then compare it to the value I am looking for.

This Thread can be closed :D Thanks to all of you who helped me.